# I developed a personal website between 2 interviews with the same company. Is it good to show them in the second interview?

Tags: interviewing, australia

I will be having my second round of interview this week with the same recruiter but different tech person. I did have an initial interview 2 weeks ago. Between those interviews, I decided to develop a personal website with the purpose of **showing my previous experiences**.

So my questions are:

> is it a positive thing to show it in the second interview? Or will I be seen as desperate/petty?

and

> if it's a positive thing (or even neutral), how do I bring it up without making them think that I'm bragging. (I don't want them to think I'm bragging for such a simple site)

Note: I built the website because they wanted to talk about my commercial experiences. And I honestly didn't remember all of them thus the idea of making my own personal site.

**Edit**

I was interviewing for a graduate position. I got the offer and decided to negotiate the salary. They want to interview me again for a developer position.

My goal is not to brag about the site (it's a simple site). I only want to show my previous experiences **through** the site. The problem is I'm afraid to miss out some important points when they ask about my commercial experiences. With this site, it's easy to refer back and make my answers clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, if you're excited about showing the site and feel it demonstrates your capabilities.**

The site does more than just demonstrate technical skills or document your past experience (although those are definitely things it can do):

- If you've included content (blog, articles, etc.) then you're demonstrating a **willingness to document and share your knowledge in a way others can use.**
- If you include pages about or links to your personal projects, the site **enriches your resume by adding depth to accomplishments.**
- You've gotten at least one page posted, this demonstrates **an understanding of web infrastructure and web technologies.**
- If nothing else, **openly sharing your work is an admirable quality in itself.** Especially in junior roles, many individuals are entirely unwilling to accept broad review or criticism of their work.

---

As requested, some potential ways to bring it up:

1. Include a link on your resume
2. Use the website as a substitute for a card - “I’d enjoy keeping in touch - all my contact info is on my website.”
3. When introducing yourself to an interviewer or recruiter, invite them to learn more about you on your webpage
4. Use it in the interview if it is an accomplishment that best demonstrates your capabilities and is relevant to a prompt provided by the interviewer. Talk about your experience developing it and creating the content for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! would you mind sharing your opinion on how should I bring it up? I don't want to make them think I'm bragging.

Comment: @kkesley in my opinion job interviews are one of the few times in life when it's not only OK to brag, it's both expected and in your best interests.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on the level of the position you're interviewing for (assuming of course that you're interviewing for a role that involves building websites).

For an entry or junior level position it could show that you're self driven, and enthusiastic about the work.

For a more senior position it could easily be construed the opposite way - if the best thing you have to talk about is a website you made between interviews then that's not exactly a glowing endorsement of years of experience.

Even for the entry level position I'd wait and see what sort of questions you get asked, and bring it up if (and *only* if) either

- The interviewer asks a question where the natural answer involves talking about websites you've designed and/or delivered

or

- You get to the *"Is there anything you'd like to talk about"* part of the interview, and don't feel that you've had a chance to make your technical skills shine through yet.

---

After reading your additional edited-in information, I wouldn't use a website to prompt your responses about previous experience, regardless of the level of the position. It would likely be awkward and time consuming to get it displayed in the interview, and reading answers to interview questions from the internet wouldn't be a very good look. I know that's not what you meant, but it's easily how it could be perceived.

Another option to achieve the same thing could be to make bullet points of things you want to cover in a notebook, and refer to it in the interview.

Make notes of what the interviewer says to you about the company in the same book during the interview as well (especially their answers to your questions) and instead of looking unprepared and/or unconfident of what you're talking about, it will make you look attentive and engaged.

Used properly, a notebook can be a great asset to you in an interview. I've had a lot of success using them in mine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The purpose of the website is to show my commercial projects, not bragging about the website itself. It's just because I'm really afraid that I missed/forgot some things about my previous experience. I'll edit my question for clarification

Comment: @kkesley I've added to my answer in response to your edit

Comment: Thanks @PlayerOne! You brought some good points which I never thought about before. Do you think it's a good idea to include the link in the thank you email? something like "thanks for the interview, if you wish to see further details about my experience, you can visit my site through (url)."

Comment: @kkesley possibly (although sending a thank you email sounds strange to me. It could be common where you are though :) ). I think whether it's worth including depends a lot on the points that Jay brings up in his answer. Personally, if I was going to include it anywhere, I'd probably put the link in my CV.

Comment: actually I don't know the culture in my area (Australia). I'm an international student. Probably it's too late now as they already got my CV before I developed this. Thanks a lot for your insight! I'll try to review my experiences while I write contents in my site instead so I'll be better prepared.